# Angular2,Typescript:How to insert a key:value pair at a PARTICULAR index in an array?

Tags: arrays, object, typescript, key-value, angular2-directives

I want to insert a key value pair at a particular index in an array.How do I do that ?

this is my code so far:

```
  this.quiz.push(
{
  "question-no":this.no,
  "Ans":this.ans
}
```

I need it in that way because this is to store the choice selected by the user against the particular question. So if the user changes the choice then that has to get replaced at that particular position(index of the array). But now a new element is being created.But I want it to replace the existing one. 
But I don't know how to insert it at a particular index.Can anyone help me please ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?v=example) function to insert at specific index.

```
this.quiz.splice(insertIndex, 0, newItem);
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks so much it works  for a single element but how do I store a key:value pair using splice() ?

Comment: @Impromptu_Coder, you need to have an object for key: value pair.
eg: var newItem = { "test": "test" }

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please check this. I need help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44455814/angular2-typescript-how-to-put-the-radio-button-checked-when-in-an-array-which

Comment: yeah, I will look at it. But you don't seem to accept answers of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simply replace the existing element at an specific index:

```
this.quiz[index] = {
  "question-no":this.no,
  "Ans":this.ans
};
```

E.g.:

```
this.quiz[4] = {
  "question-no":this.no,
  "Ans":this.ans
};
```

Note that whatever was at index 4 will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

try to use `arr.splice(index, 0, item);` at the specified index , 0 item will be deleted.

Comment: thanks a lot. Could you please tell me how to store key:value pair using splice() ?

Comment: do you mean like this ? :  `let item = {"key":"value"};
arr.splice(index, 0, item);`

Comment: if the answer was useful for u  , would you please approve it :)